# Creating a class so as a function to be valid

Tags: c++, class

I have to make class named "Bag" so as this function to be correct

```
void shopping() {
    Bag<string> bag{ "Mike" };
    bag= bag + "Apple";
    //bag = bag + "Bread" + " Milk";
    //bag - "Bread";
    bag.printS();
}
```

Steps that I made:

1)Created a class "Bag" and made a constructor to ensure that "bag" has a name("Mike")

2)I overloaded de "+" operator and here is the first **problem**: I write `list.push_back(n)` (n is a string) and n is put in the "list" but this happens just in that function,how can I make this operation to be visible outside the function?

3)How can I overload a function to make `bag + "Bread" + " Milk"`( I don't know how to overload + to make this operation)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

template<class T>

class Bag {
private:
    T name;
    vector<T> list;
public:
    Bag(T name_) :name{ name_ } {};

    T& operator+(T n) {
        list.push_back(n);
        cout << list.size();   //The result is 1,that means "Apple" is in the bag
        return n;

    }   

    void operator-(T n) {
            list.erase(list.begin()+1);
    }

    void printS() {
        cout << list.size();
    }

};


void shopping() {
    Bag<string> bag{ "Mike" };
    bag= bag + "Apple";
    //bag = bag + "Bread" + " Milk";   //It's commented because it causes an error
    //bag - "Bread";
    bag.printS();    //Here the result is 0,that means "Apple" is no more in the bag.It's visible only in the function.
}

int main() {
    shopping();
    int zz;
    cin >> zz;
}
```

Comment: Your action of `operator +` is inconsistent with the general behavior of that operator. It should return a new `Bag<T>` by value, not modify the existing object and return a `T` reference. I think you're confusing `operator +` with `operator +=`. Likewise for `operator -`. See [What are the basic rules and idioms of operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading).

Comment: I don't exactly know what you are trying to achieve but this is my quick solution:

    Bag& operator+(const T& n) {
        list.push_back(n);
        for (auto i : list)    //This for shows me if there is something in the list,and "Apple" is there.
            cout << i;
        return *this;
    }